# How much of a bump does this site get on nights when there's an election?

Tags: discussion

It seems like when election returns come in there is always a question or two, often from a first time user, who is displeased with the outcomes and is looking for some kind of explanation. It isn't obvious that there is *more traffic* only that there are a few new questions. Is it possible that interest waxes with election returns? Similarly, could there be other exogenous events that increase interest in the site (I'm thinking things that would be of interest to StackOverflow, but involve politics would be candidates).

I don't have access to mod tools, and that information might be there, otherwise I'd just look it up.

Comment: The mod tools that you get from reputation do not have this information.  It's more focused on information about posts than site visits.  I do not know if diamond moderators have a more useful tool in that regard.  The [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) may have information like this, but I don't know where it would appear.